# Layout like Cards in android

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to make an android layout like Google Cards,i know there is an Open Source Libraries, however i want only the Layout and the gray hex background style. I could not find information about this, how i can make this possible? im Attaching new Google maps v7 Layout so you can get the idea.
[image: Google Maps Layout]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

bg_card.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Or just set the background of the card to #FFF and add at the bottom:

```xml
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#CCC" />
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> For everyone who doesn't care about using a library, you should use
>   a [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) from the [Android support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-cardview).
>
> [Sample code](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView).

Comment: this was a better solution for card background :D thanks, i just made the layout with X margin and works well Thanks

Comment: looks similar to what is shown in this tutorial http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/creating-card-ui.html

Comment: @zen In each `<shape>`, you can also add `<corners android:radius="3dp"/>` to get rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">#ffe3e3e3</item>
```

In your style.xml should make you happy ;-)

And for the layout, copying the card background should be enough isn't it?

Comment: well actually almost work, there is a shade under linear layout, how i can make this?

Comment: android:background="@drawable/theshade"

Answer (score 0):

We can use the LayerList as above to achieve this (OR) by using the nine patch image get same effect, we need not create nine patch image separately for this puprpose android drawable have one.

if you are using eclipse: android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light"

copy paste the above line as your View backround.

or if you are using android studio copy paste the following line:

android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"