# How to implement card layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need information about card layout with some simple example .i am not getting any example.
Please help me
Thank you

Comment: [http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-2)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/samples/BatchStepSensor/src/com.example.android.batchstepsensor/cardstream/CardLayout.html

Comment: thank you its useful material @Rems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843922/layout-like-cards-in-android

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the libraries that have been suggested already there's also an official [CardView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview.html) created **by Google** which is available as part of the `android.support.v7.widget` library.

> CardView extends the FrameLayout class and lets you show information inside cards that have a consistent look on any app. CardView widgets can have shadows and rounded corners.

In order to use this layout you have to add the following line to your `build.gradle` (at least if you're using Android Studio):

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
}
```

Afterwards you can use it like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <!-- Content -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the right and official answer

Comment: Your link points to the `RecyclerView` documentation, shouldn't it point to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview.html instead?

Comment: @Arno Absolutely yes but somehow the link isn't valid anymore and you get redirected to the RecyclerView page. I fixed the link, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There are two great libraries available for 'Cards' like layout.

- https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations ([Google Play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations))
- https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib ([Google Play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.gmariotti.cardslib.demo))

I suggest you download and install Android application called **DevAppsDirect** where you have alot of open source libarires to use, and test how they look and what they do. You can test the first library there.

Comment: +1 for DevAppsDirect. It is REALLY helpful!